# Can a comment upvote "bump" a thread?

Tags: discussion, comments

If you see this soon enough, you should be able to click [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/) and see that a [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14582/who-is-considered-a-native-speaker-of-english) was just bumped to the top of the "active" page.  The last activity for hours was me posting a comment, and it getting an upvote.  Is that really supposed to bump the question into the active page?  How does that work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You edited one of the answers, which will bump the question.